# How to get vim if I don't have internet, but I do have vim in my other linux machine?

Tags: vim

I have two CentOS machine, Say M1 and M2. In M1 there is VIM whereas in M2 there is not and from M2 machine I cannot access internet so I will not be able to do "yum install vim" from M2.

I have copied vim from M1 to M2 then also am not able to use vim in M2.
So please assist how can I use VIM in M2 now?

Comment: Are they running different architectures, i.e. i386 vs amd64?

Comment: M1 --> 2.6.32-279.el6.i686 (CentOS release 6.3 (Final))  and M2 --> 2.6.32-504.3.3.el6.x86_64 (CentOS release 6.6 (Final))

Comment: How did you install CentOS on M2? You could copy the required `*.rpm` packages on some USB key....

Comment: That's your problem. You're trying to run i686 on amd64 without a compatibility layer. Do you have ia32libs installed on M2?

Comment: How do you end up without Vim on M2?

Answer (score 1):

If M1 and M2 have the same architecture and operating system, then the binary for one should work for the other machine. Copy the binary vim file (ususally at /usr/bin/vim) from M1 to the same /usr/bin/ folder at M2, then you should be able to run vim from the terminal.

Comment: That usually won't work with a different Linux distribution (e.g. M1 running Redhat, and M2 running Debian), even on the same architecture. And that might not work with two different versions of the same distribution

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch he said that they both run CentOS.

Comment: M1 --> 2.6.32-279.el6.i686 (CentOS release 6.3 (Final)) and M2 --> 2.6.32-504.3.3.el6.x86_64 (CentOS release 6.6 (Final))

Answer (score 1):

To copy just the contents of this package you can use the package manager of your CentOS - rpm - to determine, which files belong to the vim package installed, create a tar file out of them and copy/untar on the target host.

This simple approach will only work, if there are no further dependencies missing on the target host.

However, if you "copied M1 to M2", whatever that means, it sounds as if you already did much more than that.

```
tar cvzf vim.tar.gz $(rpm -qlp {Name of Vim package})
...
```

Answer (score -1):

If M1 has Internet connection; I would use that to download the corresponding `*.rpm` Vim packages that match the CentOS version on M2 (usually distributions provide a web interface to query the packages used in a particular version and download them). Then use the local network / sneakernet to move the files to M2, and install them there via `yum`. (If you have LAN between M1 and M2 you could even tunnel your Internet access via ssh port forwarding.)

Trying to transplant binaries from mismatching operating systems / versions is just looking for trouble.